the "totalEmployeeSalary" array is accumulating values across multiple documents
The "totalEmployeeSalary" array is accumulating values across multiple documents (each identified by a unique "doc.id") instead of representing the salaries for a single day.
This is my code on how I store values to ACCOUNTING_DATA:
// Store values to ACCOUNTING_DATA
useEffect(() => {
    const addAccountingData = async () => {
        // For computations
        const totalRevenue = 12281.72;
        const totalSales = 12281.72; 
        const totalExpenses = 12281.72; 
        const totalDailyRent = 12281.72; 

        try {
            const accountingRef = collection(firestore, "ACCOUNTING_DATA");
            const emp = []; 

            const unsubscribeAccounting = onSnapshot(collection(firestore, "EMPLOYEE_DAILY_SALARY_COMP"), (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change) => {
                    const employee = change.doc.data();
                    const accountingDataRef = doc(accountingRef, change.doc.id);

                    if (change.type === "added" || change.type === "modified") {
                        console.log("Adding or modifying data for employee: ", employee.employeeId);
                        emp.push(employee);
                        console.log("Employees: ", emp);
                    
                
                        const totalEmpSalaryData = emp.map((employee) => ({
                            employeeId: employee.employeeId,
                            dailyRate: employee.dailyRate,
                            overtimeRate: employee.overtimeRate,
                            totalRate: employee.dailyRate + employee.overtimeRate,
                            quotaPay: employee.quotaPay,
                            overBreak: employee.overBreak,
                            late: employee.late
                        }));

                        console.log("Total Employee Salary: ",totalEmpSalaryData);

                        // Update or add document in ACCOUNTING_DATA
                        await setDoc(accountingDataRef, {
                            accountingDate: employee.computationDate,
                            branchCode: employee.branchCode,
                            totalRevenue: totalRevenue,
                            totalSales: totalSales,
                            totalExpenses: totalExpenses,
                            totalDailyRent: totalDailyRent,
                            totalEmployeeSalary: totalEmpSalaryData,
                        });
                        
                    } else if (change.type === "removed") {
                        console.log("Removing data for employee: ", employee.employeeId);
                        // Remove document from ACCOUNTING_DATA
                        await deleteDoc(accountingDataRef);
                    }
                });
            });
            return () => unsubscribeAccounting();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error adding accounting: ", err);
        }
    };
    addAccountingData();
}, []);

I am trying to pput values in the totalEmployeeSalary that are filtered by branch and date
